# How do I Install Riak on Ubuntu using apt

Tags: riak

The Riak KV installation using apt on Ubuntu documents links are all broken on the [documentation page](https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/setup/installing/debian-ubuntu.1.html#installing-with-apt).

Any ideas on how to do an install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the package for your favourite version of Ubuntu from https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/3.0/3.0.9/ubuntu/ for the latest release at time of writing of KV 3.0.x or from https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.9/2.9.10/ubuntu/ for the latest release at time of writing of the KV 2.9.x series. If your heart is set on a 2.2.x version (based on the link from the question) then they can be found at https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.2/

Follow the instructions on the latest version of the docs which you can find at https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.9.10/setup/installing/debian-ubuntu/ (basically `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/riak/debfile` but you can remove it later with `sudo apt remove riak`). The version 3.0.x docs will be released soon but the installation process is the same. Just be aware that for 3.0.x all `riak-admin` and `riak-repl` commands should have the hyphen replaced with a space i.e. `riak-admin` -> `riak admin`.

Although files.tiot.jp does support being used as a rhel compliant repo i.e. `yum install riak-3.0.9` is possible after configuring it as a repo, we have not added repo based `apt` support yet as that is still WIP.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks for sending me to the new web site.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it or at least up-vote it.